# Flexbox - element on the top, another to center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I achieve something like this? `#find` must be vertically and horizontally centered.

[image]

Here is my code

```
#main {
    min-height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    font-size: 1em;
}
#find {
    width: 310px;
    min-height: 320px;
    position: relative;
}
```

More code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/br32rv3y/)

Comment: This might be helpful: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use **flexbox** with `position: absolute:` on `#menu` like this

```css
#main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #B8E986;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #D0021B;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#find {
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #F5A623;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="menu">
    Menu div
  </div>
  <div id="find">
    Find div
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could create another child div and set `display: flexbox;`  to parent.

```css
#main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #B8E986;
}

#menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #D0021B;
  width: 100%;
}

#find {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.center {
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #F5A623;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="menu">
    Menu div
  </div>
  <div id="find">
    <div class="center">
      FInd div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox has made setting `margin` to `auto` a whole lot more powerful. Doing so along the flex axis now takes up any remaining space before dividing it up between the flex items. This is the holy grail of CSS, true vertical centering.

I often use this to push footers down to the bottom of the page when the content is not tall enough. Flex is awesome.

```css
#main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #B8E986;
}

#menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #D0021B;
  width: 100%;
}

#find {
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #F5A623;
  
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="menu">
    Menu div
  </div>
  <div id="find">
    Find div
  </div>
</div>
```